# CSS Transition not showing with directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, css-transitions

I'm playing with transitions and directives. I've created a Card directive that should show a clone of it self in fullscreen when clicked. The transition doesn't happen if I don't apply the altering css class in a timeout. Is that how it should be done?

```
<div ng-app='trans'>
    <div data-card class='card'>timeout</div>
    <div data-card='notimeout' class='card'>not timeout</div>
</div>
```

Between to original position and the fullscreen mode it should transition with a spin. The goto class is just so that i can add/remove transitions so that the card doesn't transition widht/height when the window is resized. I think it reads nice too =)

```
.card {
    width:10vh;
    height:14vh;
    background-color:pink;
    margin: 10px;
}
.card.goto.fullscreen {
    transition: all 0.6s linear;
}
.card.fullscreen {
    height:95vh;
    width: 68vh;
    position:absolut;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(360deg);
}
```

This is a simplified version of my directive.

```
var app = angular.module('trans', []);

app.directive('card', ['$document', '$timeout', function ($document, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link,
        scope: {}
    };

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        var clone;
        element.on('click', function () {

            if (clone) {
                clone.off().remove();
            }

            clone = element.clone();
            var spec = getCardSpecifications();

            clone.css({
                'margin': '0',
                    'top': spec.top + 'px',
                    'left': spec.left + 'px',
                    'position': 'absolute'
            });
            $document.find('body').append(clone);

            clone.addClass('goto');

            if (attrs.card == 'notimeout') {

                clone.addClass('fullscreen');
            } else {

                $timeout(function () {
                    clone.addClass('fullscreen');
                }, 0);
            }

        });

        function getCardSpecifications() {
            var spec = {};
            spec.top = element.prop('offsetTop');
            spec.left = element.prop('offsetLeft');
            spec.height = element[0].offsetHeight;
            spec.width = element[0].offsetWidth;
            return spec;
        }

    }
}]);
```

I've created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ironfredde/tt73202z/1/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with Angular itself, but with creating a new DOM node and setting a class on it right after. Such a problem is described e.g. [here](https://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/?utm_source=tuicool), and it uses the same solution as yours in the first example.

**DISCLAIMER**: The real Angular way of doing this would be [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate). What follows is a solution that is almost the same as the OP's, and one you'd only want to use if you don't want to depend on that module – but it's only ~11kb uncompressed, and 4kb gzipped. Choose wisely!

What also worked for me is waiting for the DOM node to be ready:

```
clone.ready(function() {
    clone.addClass('fullscreen');
});
```

This amounts to almost the same thing as using a 0ms timeout, but is *a.* more descriptive and *b.* works in all cases, while the timeout solution apparently sometimes fails in Firefox (see [linked article](https://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/?utm_source=tuicool)).

The second solution given in the article also reads a little more hackish (matter of opinion, really), and you'll have to retrieve the actual DOM element instead of the jqLite wrapper around it to use it.

---

Why exactly this happens, even though you are adding the class "after appending", I wasn't able to quickly find out. Perhaps `appendChild`, which `append` most likely uses internall, is asynchronous (i.e. pushes the DOM manipulation task onto the event queue)? Some more googling might be useful if you're really interested in the cause of this problem.

Comment: Sorry, that was me, this is just misleading, 'ready' may solve the issue, but it's only due to the same reason that timeout does and ngAnimate was created specifically to solve issues like this.

Comment: In this simple use-case wouldn't element.ready be better since I'm not dependent on $animate? $animate would need to do something similar internally, right? Now I don't need the whole $animate package. But I will remember to use $animate if stuff get more advanced. I will also read up on $animate.

Comment: That is actually true @Dylan, I added a disclaimer for ngAnimate.

Comment: I suppose if it gets you by,  I just don't see it any different then $timeout. ngAnimate would also allow you to do things like reverse, and a 16k dependency isn't exactly a good reason to not use something.

Comment: It's a more descriptive way of doing it (waiting for the DOM node to be ready, instead of just pushing onto the queue), and apparently using just a timeout sometimes fails to work in Firefox (see my linked article). I have also included a note on the size of the library already.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use animate to do an animation

```
 $animate.addClass(clone, 'fullscreen'
```

I had issues trying to get the dependency for animate in fiddle so

**I made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RnlKs0dTzhlbAb0g49MC?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks it works, but I like the element.ready better. No dependency on $animate.

Answer (score -1):

When changing the DOM via the directive with methods like css, you have to inform the digest loop of these changes.

In order to accomplish that you should add **scope.$apply()** after adding the css class inside your if statement. The reason why $timeout works for you is that because it calls $apply after the timeout executes.

Comment: I added it to a [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ironfredde/1s5t6u72/). Doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, just saw that does not solve the case. I suggested for you to take a look at the Angular way to make transitions with $animate: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate

Comment: Thanks. I will read up on $animate. But I like the element.ready answer, is this case when nothing more advanced is needed. So I'm not dependent on $animate

Comment: What you say it's true, but animating a class with CSS has nothing to do with angular. Angularjs does not need to be 'informed' of that.

Comment: Yep, sorry for the confusion.