# AngularJS: Directive, element.remove() and css transition

Tags: css, angularjs, directive

I am wondering if it is possible to add some kind of transition when calling element.remove() from the linking function in directive?

For example, in my directive I have:

```
       this.$timeout(function(){
            element.remove();
        },2000)
```

This is my directive html:

```
<div class="error">{{message}}</div>
```

And my error class in css:

```
.error {
width: 200px;
height: auto;
top: 60px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
right: 20px;
background-color: #383838;
color: #F0F0F0;
font-family: Museo Sans Webfont;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px #383838;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px #383838;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 24px -1px #383838;
transition: 1s;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575237/css-transition-not-showing-with-directive

Comment: @rupesh_padhye, thank you for your comment, however this is a little different question: I am removing my element from html, so there is no transition include in that.